# react-router-dom-6-4 unable to locate RouterProvider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

i installed react **react-router-dom** via NPM i.e

```
npm install react-router-dom localforage match-sorter sort-by
```

I am unable to locate the **RouterProvider**.

i tried to import it in my main file like this

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'
import router from './router.jsx'
import {RouterProvider} from "react-router-dom";


const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <Link to="about">About Us</Link>
      </div>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: "about",
    element: <div>About</div>,
  },
]);


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router}/>

{/*    <RouterProvider  router={router}/>*/}
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --port=3000",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.6",
    "localforage": "^1.10.0",
    "match-sorter": "^6.3.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
    "sort-by": "^0.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.30",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

There are no error messages on the page. Has the name RouterProvider been changed?

i found files like BrowserRouter, StaticRouterProvider and also Router. None work though as a router

Comment: See the docs: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/router-provider

Comment: @PsyLogic i followed the documentation exaclty as stated. Still does nnot work

Comment: What is `import router from './router.jsx'` that you are importing? The code declares another `router` variable, which should cause an error. Is this just a typo or copy/paste error into the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the incorrect version of `react-router-dom`. `"react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",` should be `"react-router-dom": "^6.4.0",` if you want to use data routers.

See [Using v6.4 Data APIs](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router#using-v64-data-apis).

Try to follow these steps to get the project dependency updated.

1. Kill any running development servers/code watchers/hot-reloaders/etc.
2. `cd` to the root project directory.
3. Uninstall outdated version: `npm uninstall --save react-router-dom`.
4. Install current version: `npm install --save react-router-dom`, verify the version in the package.json file was updated. Current version as of this posting is v6.16.0. You could also verify what is actually installed by running `npm list react-router-dom` from the root project directory.
5. Restart app, e.g. `npm start` or whatever your starting/run script is. It looks like yours would be `npm run dev`. I don't use `vite` so I have no idea if you would need to rebuild via `npm run build` first before re-running the app to see the latest changes.

If you have issues still, you could try also deleting the `"node_modules"` directory and re-running `npm install` to install the project dependencies, and restart the app.

Comment: hi Drew. i have tried everything you said. my page is still blank. - i even removed the "node_modules" and re-installed it via npm install. I then ran 'npm run build' and and npm run dev. - still blank

Comment: @paulkendal23 Can you check the browser console for any errors? Can you inspect the DOM to see what *is* being rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you get this error: `router` is already declared in line 5 ?

Here's a simple example to start with:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <div>Hello world!</div>,
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: i tried it. its not working. Still no error message. but for sure not able to find the routerProvider

Comment: Which version you're using ?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",

Comment: how do i update. is  it install react_router-dom@6.4. do i need to clear a cache afterwards. Finally,  I just edited my question to show my package.json

Comment: @PsyLogic i updated but still no change. the screen is still blank.is there a way to debug this. i.e check if the RouterProvider exists?